How to condition an STM tip?
I am starting work on an atomic force microscope and a scanning tunneling microscope and I wanted to ask for advice. How to proceed to get the sharpest tip and therefore the best resolution?

These days many folks just buy tips.

Finding a method that would give you a perfect STM tip is a bit of gray area, in that no method exists that would give a great tip every time. Usual methods include chemical eatching or even breaking the wire. Since the only way you will know that you have agood tip is from the images, trial and error is the only way forward. A good review of ething here :
Etching of Cr tips for scanning tunneling microscopy of cleavable oxides
